# How to make this row in GridView in a Grey color when the Checkbox is unchecked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name, JobTitle, BadgeNo, IsActive, DivisionCode
Divisions Table: SapCode, DivisionShortcut
```

And I have a GridView that I am using it to add, delete and update/edit the employees information. This information is employee Username, Name, BadgeNo, JobTitle, IsActive and the DivisionShortcut. ***IsActive is a flag that indicates if the employee is available or in an assignment.*** I made it as a checkbox and the column should show two values; Active and Inactive. In the Edit mode, the Checkbox will be displayed. If it is checked, then it means the employee is avaiable, otherwise it is inactive.

I wrote the code and everything works fine, but now I am facing only one problem which is the following: when the checkbox is unchecked that means the employee is inactive, so I want the row that shows his information to be in a grey color (like disabled).

**So how to do that?**

ASP.NET code:

```
<%-- GridView for User Management Subsystem --%>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Username" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#DEBA84" 
             CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" BorderStyle="None" 
             BorderColor="#DEBA84">
            <FooterStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
              BackColor="#F7DFB5"></FooterStyle>
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
              HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
              BackColor="#A55129"></HeaderStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true"
                                EditImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" UpdateImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" 
                                CancelImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("DivisionShortcut")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DivisionsList" runat="server" DataSourceID="DivisionsListDataSource"
                                          DataTextField="DivisionShortcut" DataValueField="SapCode"
                                          SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DivisionCode")%>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Network ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Name")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("JobTitle")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtJobTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobTitle")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Badge No.">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("BadgeNo")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBadgeNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BadgeNo")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblIsActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsActive")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="isActive" runat="server" 
                                      AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="isActive_OnCheckedChanged"
                                      Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsActive")) %>'
                                      Text='<%# Eval("IsActive")%>'/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete the record?')">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkB" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" CommandName="Delete" />
                        </span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
//for updating the (IsActive) column using checkbox inside the GridView
    protected void isActive_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkStatus = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)chkStatus.NamingContainer;

        //Get the ID which is the NetworkID of the employee
        string username = gvrow.Cells[2].Text;
        bool status = chkStatus.Checked;

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersInfoDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

        string updateIsActive = "UPDATE Employee SET IsActive = @IsActive WHERE Username = @Username";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateIsActive, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", status);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException se)
        {
            throw se;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your method on unchecked status of the checkbox you will have set the BackColor of the GrdiViewRow like this `gvrow.BackColor= Color.Gray;`

One important think is on the first load you will need to repeat similar logic of the GridView's OnRowDataBound so move it in method and reuse

```
protected void isActive_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkStatus = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)chkStatus.NamingContainer;

        //Get the ID which is the NetworkID of the employee
        string username = gvrow.Cells[2].Text;
        bool status = chkStatus.Checked;
if(!status)//this is checkbox is unchecked then set backcolor to Gray
{
gvrow .BackColor = Color.Gray;
}

.......
```

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. Could you please explain more?

Comment: It doesn't work. Why?
Is it because I already defined the BackColor of the GridView in the ASP.NET code as shown in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
    // First check Checkedbox is check or not, In Cells insert you IsActive column index
    if( e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "False" )
        GridView1.BackColor = Color.Gray;

 }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Why?
Is it because I already defined the BackColor of the GridView in the ASP.NET code as shown in my code above.

Comment: may be but id don't think so ? check it by removing from gv.